# Growth rate of strangler aerial roots in sub-tropics

Tags: growth, roots, tropical, figs

*In sub-tropical climate, like in Roatán, Honduras, how fast do aerial roots of young strangler figs grow?*

Ludwig et al. mention in their article [Living bridges using aerial roots of ficus elastica – an interdisciplinary perspective](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6706416/): "An increasing amount of information is available on the mechanical properties of roots and their mode of anchorage in the ground for a variety of herbaceous species and woody species. However, only little is known on aerial roots in woody hemiepiphytic species." A few lines down, they point to the article [Tension Wood in Aerial Roots of Ficus Benjamina L.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00394958) by Zimmermann et al. However, I cannot access that, and I'm not sure that growth rate of aerial roots is even treated there.

[image: Aerial roots]

Photo of aerial roots of unknown species that I took in Roatán last year. Didn't think about measuring growth rate back then.

Comment: Not sure this is a gardening question. Do you intend to grow strangler figs?

Comment: @kevinskio yes, in Hong Kong, sub-tropical climate